# Start a new timer based thread after previous one finished in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run this filemover function at certain time like after 60s every time. But if the previous file mover function hadn't finished then then the new thread of this function after 60s will not run.It will only run when there is no thread already running and time is 60s. How can I achieve this functionality? Thank you in advance for help.

I have limited knowledge on thread.

```
def filemover():
    threading.Timer(60.0, filemover).start()
    oldp="D:/LCT Work/python code/projectexcelupload/notprocessed"
    newp="D:/LCT Work/python code/projectexcelupload/processed"
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(oldp) if isfile(join(oldp, f))]
    #print(onlyfiles.index("hello"))
    global globalfilenamearra
    global globalpos
    for file in onlyfiles:
        if (file in globalfilenamearra):
            txt=1
        else:
            globalfilenamearra.append(file)

filemover()
```

Comment: Question should be rephrased a bit and enriched with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the principle I would suggest is a bit more different. With each execution of a thread, you have to create a lock, so that other threads are aware that some other thread is in execution in a same time. I would say the easiest way would be creating and deleting lock file. Example from the top of my head would be something like this:

```
import os
import shutil
import threading

def moveFile(source, destination):
    print("waiting for other to finish\n")
    error_flag = 0
    while(os.path.exists("thread.lck")):
        error_flag = 0
    print("creating the new lock\n")
    f = open("thread.lck", "w")
    f.write("You can even do the identification of threads if you want")
    f.close()
    print("starting the work\n")
    if(os.path.exists(source) and os.path.exist(destination)==False):
        shutil.move(source, destination)
    else:
        error_flag = 1
    print("remove the lock")
    os.remove("thread.lck")
    return error_flag


for i in range(0, 5):
    threading.Timer(1.0*i, moveFile, args=("some.txt", "some1.txt")).start()
```

Comment: Isn't this method making busy the cpu always at high cpu usage? Cause the ```while(os.path.exists("thread.lck")):``` loop will run continuously for other thread who are waiting for the thread who is using the lck file.

Comment: cause filemover is not the only function I am using. There are other function that are used to upload the file in database. I haven.t given them here. Cause I want make it simple.

Comment: That's why you've got this kind of an answer, lack of data in your question. Yes that thread is constantly busy checking for the condition. If you are searching for more optimized solution, you should consider using good old interrupts, or even make threads on a 2nd level.

Answer (score 0):

The way threads work is another one thread does not begin unless another thread is currently not working, so it makes sense that the other thread won't begin after 60 seconds unless the other one is done. what you can do
[image: a function without threads]
this program has two time.sleep() functions for example if you had a code

```
def stuff():
    print('hello threads')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('done')

stuff()
stuff()
```

but if you are using threads it would look something more like 
[image: inner workings of threads]
if you look closely you will notice that the next function starts right when the other one begins to sleep. Threads do not run concurrently, either one can be running but not two, that would be multiprocessing.
In your code you are using the `threading.Timer()` function. The issue with that is that two threads do not run at once. If you want this functionality you will have to refactor your code. you can decide to set time limits within the function you want to use threads for using the **time module** such that it sleeps after 60 seconds so that the other thread or threads can start

Although i would advice against this because it might get out of hand very quickly when it comes to maintainability if you are somewhat new to it.

Comment: But the other thread is begining in the middle of previous thread I have tested.The code is ```def hello():
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, hello)
    t.start()
    print('hello threads')
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        print(i)
    print('done')

def mainfn():
    hello()
mainfn()```